# How to upload files (.pdf, .jpg, .doc, etc) with azure b2c - Custom Policy?

Tags: file-upload, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

My client want Azure AD B2C for the sign up of is web api.

He wants his customers to upload some documents before they can register in order to prove that they can actually sign up using azure AD B2C.

I looked in the microsoft documentation, I looked for possible examples from github https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/, in search engines and I didn't find anything that could help me. I would like to know if it is possible to do what my client wants, if so how can I do it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of now it is not possible to upload the documents and images using B2C custom policy.

However, you can add custom attribute as string to store the file URL by leverage the "UX customization" feature supported by Azure AD B2C.

I would suggest you post this idea at the [Azure Feedback Portal](https://feedback.azure.com), which is monitored by the product team for feature enhancements.